# ASP.NET MVC : transfering query data to model class object in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

I have the query with a join

```
  var DetailsQuery = (from a in db.aTable
                                 join b in db.bTable on a.carID equals b.ID
                                 where a.ID==id
                                    select new
                                 {
                                     ID = a.ID != null ? a.ID : 0,
                                     aName= a.aName,
                                     carName= b.carName,
                                 }).Take(1);
```

Am I doing correct using `Take(1)`? There actually any way must be only one row with such ID, so should I write this `Take(1)` or It will work without it?

Now, I created a new model class for the view

```
public class ModifiedaTableModel
{
        [Key]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "aIDis required.")]
        public int aID{ get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "aName required.")]
        public string aName{ get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "carName required.")]
        public string carName{ get; set; }
}
```

How can I transfer this query object to this model and so I can show it in view?

Comment: If you don't know for sure you can get whole result, check if it's more than one, log some error or whatever, then take `.First()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var DetailsQuery = (from a in db.aTable
                                 join b in db.bTable on a.carID equals b.ID
                                 where a.ID==id
                                    select new
                                 {
                                     ID = a.ID != null ? a.ID : 0,
                                     aName= a.aName,
                                     carName= b.carName,
                                 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

For using the view model in the view:

```
@model <your project name>.ViewModels.ModifiedaTableModel;
```

Assume you have your view model class in "ViewModels" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
var DetailsQuery = from a in db.aTable
                   join b in db.bTable on a.carID equals b.ID
                   where a.ID == id
                   select new ModifiedaTableModel
                   {
                       ID = a.ID != null 
                            ? a.ID 
                            : 0,
                       aName = a.aName,
                       carName = b.carName
                   });

return View(DetailsQuery.FirstOrDefault());
```

View (namespace of model may be required):

```
@model ModifiedaTableModel
```

If you select only anonymous type object, an InvalidOperationException might occur during view rendering.